# Random selection of row after subsetting

Tags: r, dataframe, random, subset

I have a 10x3 NA matrix that fills one random row with random numbers between 1-100. I want to select another random row (without replacement so to speak) and fill it without knowing which row was initially filled. I am unsure how to go about the second selection. I figure I will have to find a way to subset to just rows with NA and then randomly select. If you need detail please let me know.

```
myData <- matrix(data = NA,10,3)
random row selection.
myData[sample(1:10,size = 1,),] <- c(sample(1:100,size = 1,replace = TRUE),sample(1:100,size = 1,replace = TRUE),sample(1:100,size = 1,replace = TRUE))
```

Unsure of second random selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to store the subsets individually. It can all be handled in a `while` loop:

```
myData <- matrix(data = NA,10,3)

while(sum(is.na(myData))>0){ ## while there are NAs
  if (sum(is.na(myData)[,1])>1){ ## if it is not the last row (because the last row will need differetn approach being a vector, and not a matrix)
    myData[is.na(myData)[,1],][ ## from the subset of NAs whose first column (and hence all of it) is not NA
      sample(1:nrow(myData[ ## choose one randomly
        is.na(myData)[,1],] ),size = 1),] = sample(1:100,size = 3,replace = TRUE) ## substitute it by a random vector of the same length
  } else { ## for the last one
    myData[is.na(myData)[,1],]= sample(1:100,size = 3,replace = TRUE) 
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, trying to break this down piece by piece!

Comment: Hope the new comments help more.